# Lucene query modification

Tags: java, lucene

I have a requirement where I want to modify string formatted lucene query values. 
I am taking lucene query as input from user interface and passing it to elastic.

For e.g.

Input : name:"abc" and age:26

Output expected: name: "abcmodified" and userage:26

How do I parse and modify string formatted lucene query in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking into `org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser`? It has functionality to return a Lucene Query Object from an input string. For example:

```
String rawQuery = "name:abc AND age:26";
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_45, null, new WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_45));
BooleanQuery query = (BooleanQuery) praser.parse(rawQuery);
query.clauses().get(0).setQuery(new TermQuery(new Term("name", "abcmodified")));
query.clauses().get(1).setQuery(new TermQuery(new Term("userage", "26")));
System.out.println(query);
```

Will print `+name:abcmodified +userage:26`, which is essentially what you want. Obviously you can have smarter processing using a recursive method that traverses the query based on the query type (Boolean, Prefix, Term, Fuzzy etc...)

Hope this helps!